# Invalid block type error in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

I am facing an error while opening a cytoscape file. It was all ok when I saved it and closed cytoscape, but when I tried to open it after a day it says "invalid block type". Not sure what is the problem. Please help, as it has things I have been working on for quite a while. 
Thanks in advance
Best
Devyani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, are you talking about a session file?  If so, can you send the file to us so we can diagnose what might be happening.  Unfortunately, that error comes from the unzip process, I think, which probably means that the file is corrupted.  I've seen this happen when the write gets interrupted for some reason...

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I was talking about session file. And you are right, it seems its corrupted. So, I re-did all the things again!